# How to load already existing texture in OpenGL

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have loaded an image in OpenGL by using texture. Now I want to draw same image after some time in future. So I keep texture for that image in my texture array. Now how can I load that image directly from that stored texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_…, textureID);
```